# Can't synchronize, "header broke chain ancestry"

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization

I know Ethereum had several updates over the last couple months and suffered an unintentional fork.  Before all that started, I was using an older version of Mist (maybe ~0.8.6?  Could have been older) and Geth, and decided I'd just sit it out until things stabilized.  A few weeks ago, I fired up my Ethereum and tried to sync, but started getting Geth errors implying "bad" or "unexpected" data from peers.  I figured I must have pulled down some of the invalid fork, and hoped a newer version would automatically fix things.  Today I upgraded to the latest Mist 0.8.8 and Geth 1.5.5.  And I'm getting errors like this:

```
xxx415 eth/downloader/queue.go:894] Peer xxxxxxxxxx73ab1a: header #xxx5691 [xxxxbce1.] broke chain ancestry
xxx229 eth/downloader/queue.go:894] Peer xxxxxxxxxx73ab1a: header #xxx5996 [xxxx6f63.] broke chain ancestry
xxx162 eth/downloader/queue.go:894] Peer xxxxxxxxxx73ab1a: header #xxx2349 [xxxxbfc1.] broke chain ancestry
xxx444 eth/downloader/queue.go:894] Peer xxxxxxxxxx73ab1a: header #xxx9331 [xxxxc2df.] broke chain ancestry
xxx663 eth/downloader/queue.go:894] Peer xxxxxxxxxx73ab1a: header #xxx4080 [xxxx51ac.] broke chain ancestry
xxx557 eth/downloader/queue.go:894] Peer xxxxxxxxxx73ab1a: header #xxx4418 [xxxx9349.] broke chain ancestry
```

Note I redacted some of those ID's.  I left it for about 15 minutes and saw zero progress downloading blocks.

What should I do to recover?  Do I need to blow away everything except my private keys, and resync from scratch?

Edit: I'm now seeing messages about db_upgrade.go "Converting nnnnn blocks"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it just needed more time.  Seems to be working now.

Comment: In my case, the private ethereum wallet stuck on `Header broke chain ancestry` message for over a day. Nothing is changing by itself and there's no hope of anything moving without intervention.

Comment: Connecting to the geth console (```docker exec -it private-ethereum-wallet geth attach```) and restarting the miner (```miner.stop()```/```miner.start()```) did the job for me. When the new DAG blocks were generated, everything stabilized.